# Composer: Не генерируется автозагрузка

Tags: composer, autoload

При загрузке внешнего приватного репозитория из bitbucket не генерируется автозагрузка пакета, а именно файл в корне репозитория `myFile.php`.

`composer.json:`

```
{
    "require": {
        "MyVendor/myRepo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories":[
       {
            "type":"package",
            "package":{
                "name":"MyVendor/myRepo",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source":{
                    "type":"git",
                    "url":"git@bitbucket.org:MyVendor/myRepo.git",
                    "reference":"dev-master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "files": ["myFile.php"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для нового проекта автозагрузка подтянулась нормально. Видимо проблемы были с кешом.